# Replace a complex string from a file in Node

Tags: node.js

I am trying to replace a peace of code in a file in node JS. I found answers on how to replace a string but I don't know how to deal with a more complicated string.

This is the String I want to delete

```
SingularApp.createWithAppInstanceKey(
            "123",
            "test.com",
            singularAppInit,
            "user",
            "password"
         )
```

and I found on stack how to replace a file:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/string to be replaced/g, 'replacement');

  fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

But I can't modify the result variable to replace it  with what I need.

Comment: `singularAppInit` is a string you want to replace or `SingularApp.createWithAppInstanceKey(
            "123",
            "test.com",
            singularAppInit,
            "user",
            "password"
         )` is a string you want to replace? What is the source text?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I want to replace the entire object to ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work in your case:

`SingularApp\.createWithAppInstanceKey\(((.|\n)*)\)`. So your code would be:

```
var result = data.replace(/SingularApp\.createWithAppInstanceKey\(((.|\n)*)\)/g, 'replacement');
```

Explanation:

- `SingularApp\.createWithAppInstanceKey` matches the string `'SingularApp.createWithAppInstanceKey('`
- `((.|\n)*)` matches any char or newline repeated zero or more times.
- `\)` matches the closing bracket